# iPad: how to print programmatically from app

Tags: android, ios, ipad

I have a requirement to develop a conference check-in app. What we would like is to have an attendee scan a QR code and immediately have a badge printed next to the iPad kiosk.

The problem is that we do not want the user to be required to interact with the application at all other than to place their QR code under the camera. As soon as the QR reader finds their information in the database, the printer should fire. The user only has to scan, then grab their name badge.

I have been unable to find any documentation related to printing programmatically without some sort of interaction with the user. Is this functionality possible with an iPad? If not, is it possible with an Android based tablet?

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: `UIPrintInteractionController` has a `printToPrinter:` method that doesn't display any UI

Comment: That's correct. Look for some examples here;  http://nshipster.com/uiprintinteractioncontroller/

Comment: Wow! thanks for the help and the link. Looks like exactly what I need.